# How do I a return of a function in percentage?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a function that return a number in percentage form.

Example:

```
Function variation (fv as long, pv as long) as long
    variation = (fv/pv) - 1
End Function
```

I want to know if I can return the value in percentage (0,00%) I already try in this two ways but without sucess.

```
variation.Style = "0,##%"
```

and

```
variation.NumberFormat = "0,##%"
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing the value of a number and how that number is formatted in a cell. Just return a value between 0 and 1 and let the user format it as % if they want. The type should be double rather than long. If you want a number in the range 0-100, multiply the result by 100. If you really want the return in a certain format, the return type should be `String` rather than `Long` or `Double`. But -- strings are less useful than numbers for further calculations, so I don't think that would be a good idea.

Comment: Or if this is destined for a cell return a double & format the cell.

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=vba+format+value+as+percentage&oq=vba+format+value&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.5719j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @JohnColeman I just want to know if it's possible to return the result as a number in percentage format.

Comment: A number is a number - it doesn't have a "format".

Comment: Your question is sort of like "I want to return the least common multiple of two integers, but I want it in Roman numerals, though I don't want it as a string, I want it as a number".

Comment: Maybe we are misunderstanding you - maybe you simply mean that, instead of returning a number like `0.0512` you want to return that expressed as a percentage, i.e. the number `5.12`.  If so, just change your code to `variation = ((fv/pv) - 1) * 100` (after changing the return type to `Double`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long can only ever store whole numbers. Set the return as a double to store percentages.

```
Function variation(fv As Long, pv As Long) As Double
    variation = (fv / pv) - 1
End Function
```

This would return a correct value for use in cells.

If you wanted to create a string output with the percentage sign for use as a display then just append it like so:

```
Function variation(fv As Long, pv As Long) As String
    variation = (fv / pv) - 1 & "%"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the final result has to be a number, to futher calculations.

Comment: @Vinicius Go with the double option then. That would meet your needs.